# Finding an entry in SQL within a date range is not working

Tags: sql

I have got a problem and I don't see the answer...everything seems to be ok, but damn... It wont work.

```
$statemend = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS sum FROM $TONERVERTEILUNG WHERE ls_datum BETWEEN '2019-10-31' AND '2019-03-13' AND device_serial = 'TXS00289' AND toner_farbe = 'k' ");
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch();
$delivery = $row['sum'];
```

There is(!!) an entry on 2019-09-25, so it's in between the two dates and I should get a "1" for $delivery, but I get nothing. I dont see the mistake. Any suggestions?

(I changed the variables to values in the statement to exclude errors..)

Comment: Dont you mean `BETWEEN '2019-03-13' AND '2019-10-31'`instead of `BETWEEN '2019-10-31' AND '2019-03-13'`

Comment: I changed the dates but...still no result. I also switched from COUNT() to a normal fetch array...no result.

Comment: There is a entry for 2019-09-25. Does it have device_serial = 'ABC12345' and toner_farbe = 'k'?

Comment: Show us the row you expect to be returned.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I could upload a screenshot but Im not sure how to here @ stackoverflow...so you have to believe me :)

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/G2QvP8c)

I just "vanished" the original serial....but, who cares. That is result which should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the wrong order in your between expression. The lowest value should be first.

> test_expression [ NOT ] BETWEEN begin_expression AND end_expression

BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to the value of end_expression.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I changed the order of dates but still the same...no result

Comment: In that case i would simplify the query to `'SELECT COUNT(*) AS sum FROM $TONERVERTEILUNG WHERE ls_datum BETWEEN '2019-03-13' AND '2019-10-31'` to check if that returns anything

Comment: Or even try `SELECT COUNT(*) AS sum FROM $TONERVERTEILUNG WHERE ls_datum = '2019-09-25'` to start with the simplest query

Comment: I stripped the query to your suggestion, but.....no, nothing.

Comment: If the simplest sql returns nothing, then your question and your database is not correctly synchronized, either you are pointing to a wrong database or there are no rows where ls_datum is '2019-09-25'

Comment: ls_datum is a date column, or is a timestamp included ?

Comment: DATE colum. I changed $TONERVERTEILUNG to the real name and also put that code on top on the page, so there is nothing with ifs or anything.

[SCREENSHOT](https://ibb.co/G2QvP8c)

Comment: The Code right now with the same result as before:

$statemend = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS sum FROM bordbuch_toner_vergabe WHERE ls_datum = '2019-09-25' ");
    $statement->execute();  
    $row = $statement->fetch();
    $delivery = $row['sum'];
    print $delivery;

Comment: OMG....I found it, what a stupid mistake. $statemend != $statement

Thank you for your help.... Im going to smash my head against the desk for every comment you made. Shame on me......sorry for wasting your time :(

Comment: Ah....hold on ... it's NOT working. It is working with a stripped query but it's not working with the whole, long query....

Comment: Whatever you eventually figure out, my answer to your question is correct, lowest value must come first in a between statement